# Отправка pdf файла через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На странице есть много текстовых полей и среди них есть поле с типом file, для загрузки pdf файла.

Так вот как отправлять эти данные (текст из других полей и файл из `type=file`) через ajax? Я имею ввиду что указывать в datatype, и как вообще получить этот pdf файл? `$(".uploadfile".val();` так?

Подскажите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро.
Используйте [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) для отправки файлов при помощи ajax.

Пример использования:

```
$('#form-data').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var form = $(this); // Предположу, что этот код выполняется в обработчике события 'submit' формы
        var data = new FormData();  // Для отправки файлов понадобится объект FormData. Подробнее про него можно прочитать в документации - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

        // Сбор данных из обычных полей
        form.find(':input[name]').not('[type="file"]').each(function() { 
            var field = $(this);
            data.append(field.attr('name'), field.val());
        });

        // Сбор данных о файле (будет немного отличаться для нескольких файлов)
        var filesField = form.find('input[type="file"]');
        var fileName = filesField.attr('name');
        var file = filesField.prop('files')[0];
        data.append(fileName, file) ;

        // Отправка данных
        var url = 'upload.php';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false, 
            processData:false, 
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }           
        });  
    })
```